# Haskell: Type to represent a sudoku line?

Tags: haskell, types

In Haskell, how can I create a type to represent a list of length 9 which each elements are an Int between 0 and 9?

Comment: What exactly seems to be your problem?  Without knowing what you've tried and what your problem is, answerers are going to have to guess at where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Can't there be a safer or more appropriate type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use smart constructors:

```
module Sudoku(SudokuSquare, sudokuSquare) where

import Data.Traversable(traverse)

data SudokuSquare = SSquare Int

sudokuSquare :: Int -> Maybe SudokuSquare
sudokuSquare i = if i >= 0 && i <= 9 then Just (SSquare i) else Nothing

buildRow :: [Int] -> Maybe [SudokuSquare]
buildRow = traverse sudokuSquare
```